# Redirect with adding php param

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to set permanent redirect from

```
/models_com/dpanorama/
```

to

```
/models_com/dpanorama/?t=cm
```

How can I do that with .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !t=cm
RewriteRule ^models_com/dpanorama/$ /models_com/dpanorama/?t=cm [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me for not answering your question exactly.  I don't know exactly how to do it with .htaccess. but could you not just enforce that on your php script?  Something like:

```
if (!isset($_GET["t"])){
  $t = "cm";
}
```